# share video on facebook via iOS app always change its orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, video, orientation-changes

I am using Facebook iOS SDK version 4.0.1, When i post video on Facebook, its orientation change every time at the time of upload, i.e. When i share video which is captured in Portrait mode,at that time video share on Facebook it change to landscape mode (as i share screen shot), and when i captured in landscape mode, it change its orientation to portrait (as i shared Screenshot).

I am using following code to share video on Facebook:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *facebookShareDialog = [self getShareDialogWithVideo:assetURL]; // assetURL : video asset url from gallery or camera 
if ([facebookShareDialog canShow]) 
{
    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [self getShareDialogWithVideo:assetURL];
    shareDialog.delegate = self;
    [shareDialog show];
}

- (FBSDKShareDialog *)getShareDialogWithVideo:(NSURL *)videoUrl
{
    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    shareDialog.shareContent = [self getShareVideoContent:videoUrl];
    return shareDialog;
}

- (FBSDKShareVideoContent *)getShareVideoContent:(NSURL *)videoUrl
{
   FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
   video.videoURL = videoUrl;
   FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
   content.video = video;
   return content;
}
```

As i capture video from camera in portrait mode, and share on Facebook i got the follwing screen, from where i can say that facebook automatically change video orientation:

[image: screen shot for share video in portrait mode]

and when i share landscape video , it rotates automatically and get following screen:

[image: screen shot for share video in landscape mode]